# SQL Table Relations

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, relation

We have lots of tables in MS SQL that created without table relations many years ago. Now we are trying to create a relationship between these tables. The problem is in many of these developers used fake ids in the tables.

For example:
TABLE A, ID(primary key) -> TABLE B, AID needs to be relational. But developers used some fake ids like -1,-2 to solve some problems in their side. And now when I try to create a relation between TABLE A, ID(primary key) -> TABLE B, AID, I am getting errors.

**TABLE A**

```
ID | NAME
1  | name01
2  | name02
```

**TABLE B**

```
ID | NAME   | AID
1  | name01 | 1
2  | name02 | -1
3  | name03 | -2
```

Is there way to solve this problem and is it meaning full what developers did, they didn't use any relations in sql, they are controlling everything in code-behind.
Thanks

Comment: Hm, one thought: If the software still exists and tries to create -3 in B then the software may crash if a constraint disallows this.

Comment: @KekuSemau, I would think that was part of the point of adding the relations. This is going to be an _efficient_ way for user11022631 to uncover _a lot_ of bugs in the software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add those to your reference table.  Something like this:

```
insert into a (id, name)
     select distinct aid, 'Automatically Generated'
     from b
     where not exists (select 1 from a where b.aid = a.id) and
           a.id is not null;
```

Then you can add the foreign key relationship:

```
alter table b add constraint fk_b_aid foreign key (aid) references a(id);
```

Comment: Nice answer to solve the problem quickly. If the Automatically Generated records are not desired, then the only way is to fix manually the wrong values, and then create the foreign key relationship.

Answer (score 0):

The general idea of [referential integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity) is exactly that you *can't* have invalid references.

So the best course of action here would be to suck it up and manually clean it up. Create the missing entries in the other table, or delete the records.

Answer (score 0):

You can also ignore checks on existing data. If you are using sql server management studio to create relations there is option to do that just like in this screen shot

[image]

Hope it helps

Comment: You _can_ do this, but it will undermine your entire effort of making the DB relation-based.